# KML Layer Ordering

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have created KML files from esri Shapefiles to be used in google earth. The issue is when I bring in the two files bottom set of polygons will show the lines over the top polygons hiding a portion of the area.

I have seen people reference something about code but I was hoping someone could offer a different non-coding solution or explain better where this code would go and how it works.

Its not making sense to me.

I have tried changing the position of the two layers but any way doesn'f bring the smaller set of polygons to the top.

What I am looking for is the smaller set of polgyon lines to be completely visible while on top and the larger polygon set to be behind the first one

Answer (score 0):

If you want one polygon to always be on top of another where both are *clampedToGround* then the [gx:drawOrder](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxdraworder) property should be used.

Note the documentation (see below) only specifies LineStrings but also works for Lines, LinearRings, and Polygons. Anywhere "LineStrings" is mentioned below just replace it with Lines, Rings, and Polygons. The drawOrder support for Polygons is undocumented but is implemented in Google Earth nevertheless.

KML Documentation:

> `<gx:drawOrder>`
>
> "An integer value that specifies the order for drawing multiple *line
>   strings* (or polygons). *LineStrings* drawn first may be partially or fully
>   obscured by *LineStrings* with a later (or higher) draw order. This element may
>    be required in conjunction with the `<gx:outerColor>` and `<gx:outerWidth>`
>   elements in `<LineStyle>` when dual-colored lines cross each other."

In example below, the Red polygon is drawn over the blue polygon. To make the blue polygon draw over the red one change its drawOrder value to a higher number.

```
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Red Polygon</name>
            <description>gx:drawOrder=3</description>
            <Style>
              <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
              </LineStyle>
              <PolyStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
              </PolyStyle>
            </Style>
            <Polygon>
                <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                        14.456906,37.345497,0 14.949769,37.346531,0
                        14.960918,37.987563,0 14.45089,37.987521,0
                        14.456906,37.3455,0 
                    </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>        

        <Placemark>
            <name>Blue Polygon</name>
            <description>gx:drawOrder=2</description>
            <Style>
              <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
              </LineStyle>
              <PolyStyle>
                <color>ffff0000</color>
              </PolyStyle>
            </Style>
            <Polygon>
                <gx:drawOrder>2</gx:drawOrder>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                        14.83626,38.016863,0 14.835535,37.645589,0
                        15.47025,37.589266,0 15.470457,38.019158,0
                        14.83626,38.016862,0 
                    </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
 </kml>
```